# How to use Bootstrap JS-plugins like accordion with Angular single page application (using .otherwise method)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-accordion

I am working on a simple SPA with angular-ui-router.

However, I used Bootstrap accordion in the accordion state but as you guess the accordion behavior doesn't work unless I comment the otherwise method because any foreigner piece in the URL will take me back to the root project. How can I use both [accordion, .otherwise method]?

Here is app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: '',
    controllerAS:''
  })
  .state('accordion', {
    url: '/accordion',
    templateUrl: 'accordion.html',
    controller: '',
    controllerAS: ''
  })
});
```

And accordion.html from bootstrap:

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NwYPAI8mKQgSjk52bcI7?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

use ui-bootstrap plugin for angular

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. in this case and for the benifit for all can u tell the steps needed to include the files and also where will DI be?

Comment: there is getting started section on the same link, just read it carefully and you will get the idea :)

Comment: @Sam9 i was trying all day to acheive the desired behavior, however i kinda got it but not too pleased as im having trouble understanding the ui-bootstrap,, i need to ask you do i need to creat a separate module and inject it into my module?